# Italian melon flavored green cream liqueur?

Tags: liqueur

I am currently searching a liqueur in my memories.

It was in Milan, in the winter of year 2017. After having a pizza for lunch, I was offered a small portion of liqueur as a dessert. It was green and thick, melon flavored liqueur. I think it was some kind of a cream liqueur, but I'm not sure.

Is there any candidates matching these clues?

Comment: Was it definitely green? Otherwise Meloncello would seem to fit your description. Maybe they do make a green one, but I haven't seen it.

Comment: If it was sweet, it could perhaps be Midori?

Comment: Midori is clear and light, not creamy or thick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer from a Local.

You most probably had a PISTACCHIELLO (made from pistachio) , is common sense here in milan, after you are having a classic neapolitan pizza , that you are given 3 bootles of liqueur, and you can pour it as much as you want.

They usually came in these colors :

- yellow (limoncello from lemons)
- green (PISTACCHIELLO from pistachio)
- orange (MELONCELLO from cantaloupe)

i'm pretty sure you are you do not remember very well the colours as described earlier, but if your favourite was the cantaloupe one was the orange, otherwise it was PISTACCHIELLO.

That said, i don't know if there is request for this product outside milan and amalfi coast, try searching on google for

PISTACCHIELLO
MELONCELLO.

Answer (score 1):

**Italian melon flavored green cream liqueur?**

The closest I could find would be the Italian Melon Cream Liqueur.

> **Melon Cream Liqueur**
>
> This was the one we were most excited to taste. With the limited selection of melon liqueurs available on the market, they all taste as artificial as their green coloring. Upon first taste, we were not disappointed. Like a sweet fresh cantaloupe, this was every bit what we wanted in a true melon liqueur. The cream takes a back seat is this drink, letting the Assisi melon taste take the stage. We had to investigate this melon as it tasted so similar to cantaloupe. It turns out that the melon is named for the city it’s grown in, Assisi, Italy. The only thing we can really compare this liqueur to is the time we got over excited about a new juicer and ran an entire cantaloupe through it. Time well spent. - [Francescano Liqueurs](https://www.happy-harrys.com/francescano-liqueurs-new-product-review/)